# Get methods doesn't show <example> documentation in Azure Api Management developer portal

Tags: azure-api-management, swashbuckle

I have an API with Swashbuckle 5.5.1, and GET methods doesn't show documentation properly at Azure Api Managment developer portal, but the documentation is showed correctly at swagger portal.
For example.This code only shows documentation at Swagger portal:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The total amount of the invoices.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>10.59</example>
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The status of the invoices.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>1</example>
    public AffiliateInvoiceStatusModel Status { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The invoice type of the invoices.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>2</example>
    public InvoiceTypeModel InvoiceType { get; set; }
```

Capture of documentation at Swagger
[image]

Capture of documentation at Azure Api Management developer portal
[image]

Is there any way to show documentation for GET methods? It is necessary some type of configuration at developer portal, it's seems to ignore some values at swagger.json.

POST, PUT or DELETE methods documentation is showed correctly.

Comment: If Swagger shows it but Azure does not then this is clearly something at azure... have you reach out their support?
https://portal.azure.com/?quickstart=true#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now this is not supported, but we're working on improving APIM OpenAPI support.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote at Microsoft forums support and the ETA is at the end of september.